# subtract all rows with the same id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my real problem

how can i subtract all rows with the same id?

here is my query to subtact

```
SELECT amount - (SELECT amount 
                   FROM tblmonth WHERE id2='1' 
                   AND  type='budget') 
FROM  tblmonth 
WHERE id2='1' 
and   type='actual'
```

the problem in this query is, it only can subtract one at a time by using the id2='1'.

please see image below for reference. thank you

[image]

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: The error you're getting is, as it says, because you have more than one "amount" for at least one of those subqueries... Maybe you want to SUM the amount or something in the subqueries?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a reason to use subqueries.  The logic might be best expressed as:

```
select sum(case when type = 'budget' then amount
                when type = 'actual' then -amount
                else 0
           end)
from tblmonth
where id = 1
```

Comment: thanks for this, ill try to use this. ill update you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your id is a PK, so use top 1 to make sure the query return only one record. If it should return more than one, you can use SUM() function

```
SELECT TOP 1 ( SELECT TOP 1 amount FROM tblmonth where type = 'budget' and id='1') 
           - ( SELECT TOP 1 amount FROM tblmonth where type = 'actual' and id='1')
as Result
from tblmonth
```

> Select Top 1 as your result is return only one record,does need to return the number of table tblmonth record of those result.

Comment: thank for this, i put a wrong id column to match, but here's the my query now and it works. `SELECT amount - (SELECT amount FROM tblmonth WHERE id2='1' AND type='budget') FROM tblmonth WHERE id2='1' and type='actual'`